# Split an hourly schedule into minutes using Excel

Tags: python, arrays, excel

I have a huge data dump where each line is as follow:

```
|hour|number of items|destination|
```

There are 24 hours (a whole day) and 9 different destinations. The challenge is to split it up so that I have a breakdown by item. For instance this:

```
|1|5|Kitchen|
|1|2|Bedroom|
```

Should become this:

```
|1:10|1|Kitchen
|1:20|1|Kitchen
|1:20|1|Bedroom
|1:30|1|Kitchen
|1:40|1|Kitchen
|1:40|1|Bedroom
|1:50|1|Kitchen
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to best do this using Excel. If push comes to shove, I could also use python to transform the data although not my preferred solution.

Comment: Ok, so in your scheduling, Bedroom and Kitchen can be done at the same time. Nothing in your question constrains the output to that _specific_ output. Why cant you do both Bedrooms alongside the first two Kitchens?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the question. The only restriction on the output is that it be 1 items per row. Does that help?

Comment: Not really, I'm asking why Bedroom can't be at `1:10`

Comment: Please explain the output format.

Comment: Looks like he means that in hour 1, there are 5 kitchens and 2 bedrooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop to go through all the data and have a counter variable for all 9 destinations. Use Split to get the right data from the data. Here is some pseudocode which can help you:

```
HourVariable = 0
For i = 1 to endOfdata
  dHour = split(split(dataline(i),"|")(1),":")(0) 'Get the hour from the dataline
  If Hourvariable <> dHour then 'Check if the hour changed. In that case the data for that hour needs to be written and all counters go to 0
     If cKitchen > 0 then NewData = NewData & "|" & dHour & "|" & cKitchen & "|Kitchen|" & vbNewLine
     If cBedroom > 0 etc...    
     cKitchen = 0
     cBedroom = 0
     HourVariable = dHour
     Select case split(dataline(i),"|")(3) 'Check which destination is in the current dataline
       Case "Kitchen": cKitchen = cKitchen + 1
       Case "Bedroom": etc...
     End Select
  Else 'In other cases, just add to the counters
     Select case split(dataline(i),"|")(3) 'Check which destination is in the current dataline
       Case "Kitchen": cKitchen = cKitchen + 1
       Case "Bedroom": etc...
     End Select
  End if
next i
```